# Claims authentication with AD

Tags: 2010, authentication, active-directory, claims-based-auth

I'm very new at this claims based authentication, and I just set up a sharepoint site with claims, with FBA access through a regular asp.net membership db.

This works just fine.

What I now need is to also be able to login with AD, on a different domain than the server is hosted on.

That is to say, the server is on domain A and I need to allow for users on domain B to log on too. Do I have to use ADFS to accomplish this? Is there now quick and easy way of doing it?

/Dynde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can create a trust relationship between the two domains, then you can add "Integrated Windows authentication"

If you cannot create a trust relationship, then you will likely need an external identity provider for SharePoint. ADFS2.0 is Microsoft's identity provider in this space.

Comment: Only additional comment is it only needs to be a one way trust. i.e. Domain A trusts Domain B.  You shouldnt need a two way trust.  This may help the secruity people un-bunch their pants when you ask for it.

Comment: Thanks - I also read something about using Active Directory provider using FBA - would this work for my particular case?